# Move to Midline in Terminal?

Tags: zsh, emacs, macintosh

I frequently make spelling mistakes in the middle of my commands in my zsh iterm2 (on Macbook). For example, the word "origin" below

```
git push origi my-very-long-branch-name
```

My normal inefficient way to correct this is to move the beginning of the line with `ctrl + a`, then hit my right arrow until I reach the spelling error. If the spelling error was closer to the end of the line, I'd do `ctrl + e`, then hit my left arrow until I reached the point.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps a command to move to the midpoint of the line?

- I believe my mac zsh iterm2 uses gnu. I saw `M-f` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html), but I don't know what they mean by the mouse button. Trying to click for me does nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest you get a proper tab completion and avoid spelling errors in the first place.

Comment: Fair for this example! Sometimes the spelling errors are names of things, which would not be auto completable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> to move one word forward and
<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> to move one word backward. It should be
much faster than moving one character at a time using arrow keys.

Additionally, you can move by n words at the time by first providing an
universal argument using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>,
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some more options:

- [that mouse support](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/mouse.zsh) for zle I wrote a few years back (more as a proof of concept, I've not used it myself as I don't really use mice much).
- In `emacs` mode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for incremental search in `R`everse, and enter `gi` for instance (`^R` again to repeat the search, `^S` to go in the other direction).
- In `vi` mode, you can use `?` in command mode as the equivalent of `^R` above (`n` to repeat, `N` in the other direction), or use the `T` (go `t`o a character backward) or `F` (go `f`or a character backward) motions like in `vi`. Here as `Ti` for instance to go `T`o the `i` character (and `;` to repeat the previous to/for motion)
- In `vi` mode, see the `b`, `B` motion to go `b`ack one word or Word like in `vi`. And `3B` to go back 3 Words. Those would be the equivalent of [the `emacs` word motions mentioned by @Arkadiusz](/a/625888).